# How do I stop a QML drawer from being swiped?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm making a side menu using a Drawer and I want to stop the user from swiping the drawer. The drawer should open and close based on button clicks. Is there any way to achieve this or am I better off creating my own component?

```
Drawer {
   id: menu
   width: 0.37 * parent.width
   height: parent.height
   edge: Qt.RightEdge
   closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose

   Button {
      id: option 
      onClicked: menu.close() 
   }
}

Button {
   id: menuButton
   onClicked: menu.open()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the [`interactive`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html#interactive-prop) property of the [`Drawer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html) to false:

```
Drawer {
   id: menu
   width: 0.37 * parent.width
   height: parent.height
   edge: Qt.RightEdge
   closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose
   interactive: false

   Button {
      id: option 
      onClicked: menu.close() 
   }
}

Button {
   id: menuButton
   onClicked: menu.open()
}
```